# How can I get Currency object using a number

Tags: java, android, currency

I got a service that's sending me the currency ID of the currency I should work with.
The ID is a number that represents an ISO-4217 Currency.

The java Currency object enable to get an instance according to the currency string ID (i.e USD, JPY...), but not according to the ISO number code (i.e 840, 392...)

How can I get an instance using the number value?

Comment: You want to work out the currency by examining the number? So, what currency is 42.00 then?

Comment: He is referring to the three-digit ISO 3166-1 numeric codes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_numeric

Comment: Ah, I see. Edited accordingly.

Comment: @Graham: ISO 3166? He's specifically asking for the ISO 4217 codes.

Comment: @jarnbjo OK, to be absolutely precise, the ISO 4217 currency codes have three-digit numeric codes which are **usually** the same as the ISO 3166-1 numeric codes. Please let us know if you spot any differences between the two.

Comment: @Graham: There are many differences between the numeric ISO 3166 and 4217 codes, particularly where a country has changed its main currency (e.g. Poland), where several countries share one currency (e.g. the Euro area) or where one country uses multiple currencies (e.g. Cuba).

Answer (score 3):

Maven artifact **com.neovisionaries:nv-i18n:1.9** contains **CurrencyCode**, which is a Java enum listing all ISO 4217 codes. With CurrencyCode, getting a Currency instance from an ISO 4217 numeric code can be written like the following.

```
import java.util.Currency;
import com.neovisionaries.i18n.CurrencyCode;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Get the Currency instance for 392 (Japanese Yen).
        Currency currency
            = CurrencyCode.getByCode(392).getCurrency();

        // This prints "JPY".
        System.out.println("currency = " + currency);
    }
}
```

nv-i18n project page:
https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-i18n

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.neovisionaries</groupId>
    <artifactId>nv-i18n</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 7 (probably not working on Android, unless Android supports Java 7), the numerical code is included in the currency data, but there is unfortunately (for some strange reason) not a static lookup method for it in the Currency class.

You can implement such a method yourself, potentially creating a lookup map for performance optimization instead of iterating through all currencies in each invocation:

```
public static Currency getByCode(int code) {
    for(Currency c : Currency.getAvailableCurrencies()) {
        if(c.getNumericCode() == code) {
            return c;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unkown currency code: " + code);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately your example won't work. Android uses a subset of the Apache Harmony SE 6. Neither `getAvailableCurrencies()` nor `getNumericCode()` are supported for `Currency` in Android.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the Android tag.

Comment: No problem - I even had to check which version Android supports myself and I develop for Android all the time. Other than that, your code sample is sound. :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a Map which maps the number to the ISO String.

```
class MyISO4217Mapper {
    private static final Map<Integer, String> mapOfISO4217 = new HashMap<>();


    static {
        // create static mappings here:

        mapOfISO4217.put(710, "ZAR");
        // .
        // .
        // .
        mapOfISO4217.put(840, "USD");
    }

    public static Currency getISOCode(Integer id) {
        String isoCode = mapOfISO4217.get(id);
        return Currency.getInstance(isoCode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ISO 4217 currencies can be found in the following location in xml format:

http://www.currency-iso.org/dam/downloads/table_a1.xml

You can save the file inside your application and use a bit of xpath to extract the relevant currency code which you can then use in `Currency.getInstance(String currencyCode)`.